# Radio buttons give wrong value in php

Tags: php, html, forms, session

So, I am trying to make a login + register page in-one. Where I use radio buttons to get the value if you want to login or register.
Here is the radio button s code;

```
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="check" id="check" value="1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="check">Register</label>
            <br>
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="check" id="check" value="0" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="check">Login</label>
        </div>
```

So, I am checking for `$_POST['check']` if the value is `0` or `1`. But somehow it just ignores that, and always registers. Here is my php code;

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
   $value = $_POST['check'];
   // Do some stuff here
   if ($value == 1) {
      // register
   } elseif ($value == 0) {
      // login
   } else {
      // Do something for bad results
   }
}
```

Somehow when I check `login` it wants to register, but when I click on register, it still registers. Something is going wrong here right?

Comment: Try `$value == "1"` and `$value == "0"`

Comment: And what will change?

Comment: @Twinkle `1 == "1"` is true in PHP

Comment: You can var_dump($_POST['check']) to find out what you are receiving

Comment: @Twinkle it still only registeres

Comment: I tried your code and I have the expected result. `$value` might be overwritten in the `// Do some stuff here`. This is by the way a **very bad** naming which can lead to confusion/overwritting.

Comment: I agree with user @Cid; tested your code as is and it worked as intended for me. Perhaps posting more code may be appropriate to identify the issue.

Comment: @Twinkle it works!

Answer (score -2):

`id` of element must be unique

code should look like this

```
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="check" id="check_1" value="1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check_1">Register</label>
        <br>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="check" id="check_0" value="0" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check_0">Login</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Although this is fixing an invalid HTML, this has nothing to do with the problem.